# Grails 3 CSRF protection

Tags: grails, spring-security, csrf, grails-3.0

Is it possible to configure CSRF protection in grails3 app using spring-security plugin, I can't find anything except useToken attribute for grails form and then call withForm inside controller. But this is actually not a very flexible solution. I like approach with filter like [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#servlet-csrf-configure)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For csrf protection I reused **org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter**. You need to define new bean in grails resouces.groovy (See snipet below - **csrfFilter** bean). You can define your own **accessDeniedHandler** and **requireCsrfProtectionMatcher**. Here is the snippet from resources.groovy:

```
csrfFilter(CsrfFilter, new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository()) {
    accessDeniedHandler = ref('fnAccessDeniedHandler')
    requireCsrfProtectionMatcher = ref('fnRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher')
}
```

Now in Bootstrap.groovy add this filter into filter chain:

```
 SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('csrfFilter',    SecurityFilterPosition.LAST.order + 10)
```

Now in your main layout GSP add following tags to add csrf token on each page:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf?.token}"/>
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf?.headerName}"/>
```

So now csrf token presented on each page of your app, you can use it for each ajax request for example (snippet from application.js (I'm using grails 3)):

```
$(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
```

For each jquery ajax request we are sending csrf token now.

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example of your custom *accessDeniedHandler* and *requireCsrfProtectionMatcher* classes?

Comment: Old thread but in case it helps, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307781/how-to-write-accessdeniedhandler-in-grails
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098323/scpting-security-requirecsrfprotectionmatcher-with-csrftokenrepository

Answer (score 4):

You can implement it with **<g:form>** tag:

**Example:**

```
<g:form useToken="true" uri="/logout">
```

**Documentation:** http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#formtokens

In my case, I'm using Spring code, so, additionally, I should add manually a _csrf hidden field in the form.

```
<g:form useToken="true" uri="/logout">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <input type="submit">Logout</input>
</g:form>
```

**Result:**

```
<form action="/nacho/logout" method="post" >

    <!-- this two lines are added automatically by Grails -->
    <input type="hidden" name="SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN" value="883a1037-a2c9-4997-8254-e59da6303494" id="SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN" />
    <input type="hidden" name="SYNCHRONIZER_URI" value="/nacho/userInfo" id="SYNCHRONIZER_URI" />

    <!-- this line was added by myself, but, using the ${_csrf} variable -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="0928f13c-02aa-4122-8ebe-a1239855a85b"/>

    <input type="submit">Logout</input>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, but then on the backend you always should use withForm method, this is ugly solution. The best option is to use CrsfFilter from spring security, I managed to set it up, now it works fine, but thank you for reply :)

Comment: @enzo Could you share your configuration? Perhaps by submitting it as an answer to this question? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: @EdJ see my answer above, ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: @enzo one question friend: I have multiples form in my project. Should i add in my main.gsp: $(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});