# Grails - Spring Security plugin: Enabling CSRF filter

Tags: grails, spring-security

I know that Spring Security added built-in CSRF protection in version 3.2.0 as stated here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html

I am using Grails 2.4.3 with the spring-security-core plugin version 2.0.0 which seems to use Spring Security version 3.2.3, however, the CSRF protection is either not enabled or not present.

I'm wondering if there's a way to turn it on in the plugin that I am missing. Is there a way to use one of the configuration methods mentioned in the link with this plugin? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

I know that later versions have this on by default, but upgrading Grails version is not an option for me, and later versions of the spring-security-core plugin require Grails 3.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no default CSRF protection in any version of Grails spring security plugin. 
According to the spring security doc

> 1) You need to be certain that your application is using PATCH, POST, PUT, and/or DELETE for anything that modifies state
>
> 2) Include the CSRF token in all PATCH, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods

Grails can generate and check the token for you, just use `<g:form useToken="true" ...>` for all form submitions. Check it [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/security.html#securingAgainstAttacks). Bun then you have to modify all controllers.

Otherwise you have to use some custom solution, e.g you can create a service for token generation, call it from gsp:

```
<g:set var="token" bean="tokenService"/>
<g:form token="${token.getToken()}">
```

And create a filter, to validate a token from every PATCH, POST, PUT, and DELETE requests

Comment: According to [https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html] documentation, CSRF protection is enabled by default in the latest versions of Spring Security.  In the latest versions of grails CSRF tokens can be utilized by creating forms with `<g:form useToken="true" ...>`.  See http://docs.grails.org/2.4.5/guide/single.html#formtokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38053797.

I implemented this on grails 2.5.6. Hope this helps!