# How to enable CSRF in Grails using Reactjs front-end + spring security

Tags: reactjs, grails, spring-security, csrf

I want to enable CSRF in my Grails application with Reactjs front-end. I have not seen any clear steps in the documentation on how to go about this.

I have configured my header to send a CSRF-token when making any request to the backend:

```
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${ *********, 'access_token')}`,
    'X-Csrf-Token':Cookie.load('XSRF-TOKEN')
```

Please I need help on how to intercept the request in the backend and validate the CSRF-TOKEN.

**EDIT**

I came across an article from which I implemented this:

```
@Configuration
class CorsFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration()
        config.setAllowCredentials(true)
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*")
        config.addAllowedHeader("*")
        config.addAllowedMethod("*")
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source))
        bean.setOrder(0)
        return bean
    }
}
```

My current issue now is including XSRF-TOKEN in my headers. My current implementation is not working.

Comment: Have you checked out this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806053/grails-spring-security-plugin-enabling-csrf-filter

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the post. It was not very helpful since the front-end was implemented using gsp.

Answer (score -1):

also the spring-security-rest plugin which handles tokens addressed this : https://gitter.im/alvarosanchez/spring-security-rest?at=566e32a26a17cd3b36dcc8e9

Also check here : https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-rest/issues/216

From the looks of things, you may have to write your own token reader (which is not hard)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Orubel. I didn't find the post useful.