# How to write accessDeniedHandler in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, csrf-protection

I am new to groovy, I have implemented CSRF Token in grails in following manner. 
CSRF filter is added in resource.groovy

```
csrfFilter(CsrfFilter, new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository()) {
        accessDeniedHandler = ref('fnAccessDeniedHandler')
        requireCsrfProtectionMatcher = ref('fnRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher')
    }
```

But i don't know how to initialize fnAccessDeniedHandler and  fnRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to point out that you don't have to provide them, you can use the defaults

Answer (score 2):

The value in ref has to be a bean(https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/spring.html). If you want to override accessDeniedHandler and requireCsrfProtectionMatcher, You would need to create custom classes, and create beans in resources.groovy. As an example, to create bean fnAccessDeniedHandler, you would do something like this.

Add the following in resources.groovy

```
fnAccessDeniedHandler(CustomAccessDeniedHandler)
```

And create a class CustomAccessDeniedHandler which implements AccessDeniedHandler.

```
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    public static final Logger LOG
      = Logger.getLogger(CustomAccessDeniedHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handle(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, 
      AccessDeniedException exc) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Authentication auth 
          = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            LOG.warn("User: " + auth.getName() 
              + " attempted to access the protected URL: "
              + request.getRequestURI());
        }

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/accessDenied");
    }
}
```