# CSRF setup on grails

Tags: grails, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm working on grails 2.5 application. I have setup CSRF configuration for my application referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38053797) and it's working fine. I'm setting the header whenever an ajax request is being sent and similarly I'm adding a CSRF parameter when a form is being submitted.

I had few queries:

1. CSRF token remains the same throughout a user session, it doesn't change for every request. Is it secure enough?
2. CSRF token doesn't reinitialize after login. I had expected that it will be renewed as soon as user gets authenticated but it remains the same as it was on the login page. Is there any way to renew it every time user gets authenticated?

Comment: You need to genrate a new token each time you submit the form, so create it with `SynchronizerTokensHolder.store(session).generateToken(inputParams.SYNCHRONIZER_URI)`

Comment: @PrakashThete Sorry, what's the problem with my implementation?

Comment: You are not changing the CSRF token on ajax request, I would recommend the new CSRF token on each request. So by using the code mentioned in above comment you can have new token on each request.